# Optimizing bubble sort code

Tags: java, performance, sorting

Please help me optimize this bubble sort code. It's working fine otherwise.

```
int[] randomIntegers = {2,3,1,1,4,5,8,-2,0};

for(int i=0;i<randomIntegers.length;i++){
  for(int j=i;j<(randomIntegers.length-1);j++){
    if(randomIntegers[i]>randomIntegers[j+1]){
      randomIntegers[i] += randomIntegers[j+1];
      randomIntegers[j+1] = randomIntegers[i] - randomIntegers[j+1];
      randomIntegers[i] = randomIntegers[i] - randomIntegers[j+1];
    }
  }
}
for(int i:randomIntegers){
  System.out.print(i+",");
}
```

Comment: As pointed out by @Guffa, this is not bubble sort (see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort), or Guffa's answer).  Also it is quite odd to swap the elements by adding and subtracting bits of them; they are usually swapped using some temporary variable.

Comment: Here's the best implementation of bubble sort I've ever seen. It's very fast and efficient. https://github.com/mirrors/linux-2.6/blob/b3a3a9c441e2c8f6b6760de9331023a7906a4ac6/drivers/media/common/saa7146/saa7146_hlp.c#L308

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you need to optimize bubble sort, you're doing it wrong. It's not really worth optimizing something that's inherently slow. You should just use a better sorting algorithm.

Comment: my sentiments exactly

Comment: You feel so strongly about bubble sort that you did not even read the code.

Comment: True :) Doesn't really make much difference if it's a selection sort or insertion sort instead. The first step in optimizing any code is to use a better algorithm.

Answer (score 7):

Well, first of all, that's not bubble sort at all.

Here's bubble sort:

```
bool swapped = true;
while (swapped) {
  swapped = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < randomIntegers.length - 1; i++){
    if (randomIntegers[i] > randomIntegers[i + 1]) {
      swapped = true;
      int temp = randomIntegers[i];
      randomIntegers[i] = randomIntegers[i + 1];
      randomIntegers[i + 1] = temp;
    }
  }
}
```

Here's an improved version of bubble sort, where the items known to be sorted are excluded:

```
bool swapped = true;
for (int i = randomIntegers.length - 1; swapped && i >= 0; i--){
  swapped = false;
  for (int j = 0; j < i; j++){
    if (randomIntegers[j] > randomIntegers[j + 1]) {
      int temp = randomIntegers[j];
      randomIntegers[j] = randomIntegers[j + 1];
      randomIntegers[j + 1] = temp;
    }
  }
}
```

On the subject of optimising the code that you have, whatever algorithm that is, you can let `j` loop from `i + 1` instead of `i`, so that you don't need to use `j + 1` everywhere. Also, use a temporary variable to swap the items:

```
for (int i = 0; i < randomIntegers.length; i++) {
  for (int j = i + 1; j < randomIntegers.length; j++) {
    if (randomIntegers[i] > randomIntegers[j]) {
      int temp = randomIntegers[i];
      randomIntegers[i] = randomIntegers[j];
      randomIntegers[j] = temp;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Umair is using a variant of the [XOR swap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm#Variations) technique to swap values without using a local temporary variable. I could tolerate it if he actually used XOR, since it would be easier to recognize, but using the subtraction variation makes it cryptic, as evidenced by your confusion.

Comment: @200_success: Yes, I regocnise it, and I'm not confused by it. (I actually suggested a variation of it in an SQL query a few days ago.) There is just no reason to use it here, using a local variable as temporary storage is shorter and more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm is nearly "selection sort" (see the [wikipedia entry on sorting algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm)).

You could make it more efficient by doing the true selection sort:  during the `j`-loop, you do not swap every time you find a value smaller than the `i`-value, but rather you just use the loop to find the minimal value to the right of the `i`-value and only after the `j`-loop is done do you swap, if needed.

Also, for efficiency, you should just swap the values by using a temporary variable (see Guffa's code for example) instead adding and subtracting bits of the numbers in-place.

But it would even better to implement the true bubble sort, or some inherently faster algorithm.  Again, take a look at the wikipedia link.